# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{\theta=1}^{89}(\csc\theta^\circ+\sec\theta^\circ)$ and $\prod\limits_{\theta=1}^{89}(\csc\theta^\circ\sec\theta^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

How do we evaluate the following sum and product?

$$\sum\limits_{\theta=1}^{89}\csc(\theta^\circ)+\sec(\theta^\circ)$$
$$\prod\limits_{\theta=1}^{89}\csc(\theta^\circ)\sec(\theta^\circ)$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3466221/edit) to add details.

Comment: Hi. I am currently in the second year of high school (11th Grade). I've never seen these symbols before. Somehow, there is some simple way to solve it for the students in 11th grade. I tried to think it by every way possible and got stuck, so I simply couldn't reach any way to solve it.

Comment: How could these problems be assigned without you having seen the symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the summation, consider some $\theta\neq45^\circ$, and $\phi=90^\circ-\theta$.

Note that $$\csc\theta+\csc\phi=\sec\theta+\sec\phi=\sqrt8\cdot\frac{\cos(\phi-\theta)}{\cos(\phi-\theta)}=\sqrt8$$(It's not hard to evaluate this via the sum/product formulas [here](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html))

So, the summation is equal to $$88\cdot\sqrt8+\sqrt8=89\cdot\sqrt8=178\cdot\sqrt2$$

For the product, try applying the same formulas, but this time, noting that the product is equivalent to $$\prod\limits_{\theta=1}^{89}\csc^2\theta=\frac1{\left(\prod_{\theta=1}^{89}\sin\theta\right)^2}$$

And you can consider $\sin\theta\sin\phi$ as in [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/numeral-value-of-this-sin-1-sin-2-sin-3-sin-89.239026/) thread. I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping, but I am in the 11th grade and I don't know what does that symbol ∏ really mean, so is there a simpler way to find the answer for the product of them?

Comment: It means product. Do not be scared of learning. You have the internet at your fingertips.

Comment: There is a little bit misunderstand here. this question is remodified by some admin here from the original one which was: csc(1)*csc(2)*csc(3)* *csc(89)*Sec(1)*Sec(2)*Sec(3)* *Sec(89).
that's why I said I don't know what is this symbol even if I knew I would take 2 days at least studying specially for this question...

Comment: That is precisely what these symbols mean. It's not as bad as it looks. Your question was edited since otherwise, it would have been closed.

Comment: I searched a little bit and kinda got what that symbol means. Now, how can I get the final answer? Do I have to calculate it manually or using a calculator? I have fx-991ARX but it doesn't have that symbol or maybe it does but I don't know where. Also, why did you equalize product operator csc^2 with 1/product operator sec^2?

Comment: @AymanTarek It isn't $1/\sec^2$. Rather, $1/\sin^2$

Comment: And note that $\csc\theta\sec\phi=\csc^2\theta$, where the variables are defined as in my answer.

Comment: and how to calculate 1/pi sinθ^2? can we use a calculator for it?

Comment: I provided a link... Forget your calculator

Comment: This answer is nonsense. The claimed identity for the secant and cosecant terms is clearly wrong: all terms summed exceed $1$, and many are much larger than $\sqrt{8}-1$. Numerically, the sum approximates $608.465$, whereas $178\sqrt{2}\approx251.73$.

Comment: @J.G. Yea I just looked over the numbers, you are correct. I'll revise in the morning, I'm exhausted right now. Don't exactly know where I goofed up yet.